# Accessing deeper array keys using function arguments

Tags: php

I am trying to create a function (unless one already exists?) which is supposed to accept an "unlimited" amount of arguments (using `func_get_args()`) to find the value of an array key. Regardless of how deep within the array it is to be found.

Say if I would use `$registry->getSetting( 'template', 'default' );` I am supposed to get the value of `$this->properties['settings']['template']['default']` or if I would you `$registry->getSetting( 'users', 1, 'name', 'first' );` I would expect it to return the value of `$this->properties['users'][1]['name']['first']` (just a second example with a couple of extra arguments).

Now, to do something like this, I could count the amount of arguments passed using `func_num_args()` and then do a switch with different cases. Although, this would limit it to a certain amount of keys.

So I am asking you if there is a way of doing this, to allow an "unlimited" amount rather than a fixed amount of arguments to access a deeper key of an array.

```
<?PHP
class Registry
{
    // Values are actually fetched from a config file, but for easier understanding
    private $properties = array(
        'settings' => array(
            'template' => array(
                'default' => 'default',
                'caching' => TRUE
            )
        )
    );

    public function getSetting( )
    {
        // do something like
        // return $this->properties['settings'][func_get_args( )];
    }
}
?>
```

Any help whatsoever is highly appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?PHP
class Registry
{
    // Values are actually fetched from a config file, but for easier understanding
    private $properties = array(
        'settings' => array(
            'template' => array(
                'default' => 'default',
                'caching' => TRUE
            )
        )
    );

    public function getSetting()
    {
        $result = $this->properties;

        foreach (func_get_args() as $arg) {
            if (isset($result[$arg])) {
                $result = $result[$arg];
            } else {
                return;
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
}

$r = new Registry();

var_dump($r->getSetting('settings', 'template', 'default'));

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I'm not sure if this is what you want, but this is straight from the PHP manual:

> ## Variable-length argument lists
>
> PHP 4 and above has support for
> variable-length argument lists in
> user-defined functions. This is really
> quite easy, using the func_num_args(),
> func_get_arg(), and func_get_args()
> functions.
>
> No special syntax is required, and
> argument lists may still be explicitly
> provided with function definitions and
> will behave as normal.

I would just loop over the arguments and output them into a single array (I might be misinterpreting your question):

```
$output = array();
$arguments = func_get_args();

foreach ($argument as $arg)
{
  $output[$arg] = $this->properties['settings'][$arg];
}

return $output;
```

Good luck?

Comment: Yes it was indeed, thank you very much. I will however accept zerkms post as he was first, thank you once again though!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a PHP function which can do this, but my way is working fine too:

```
class Registry
{
    // Values are actually fetched from a config file, but for easier understanding
    private $properties = array(
        'settings' => array(
            'template' => array(
                'default' => 'default',
                'caching' => TRUE
            )
        )
    );

    public function getSetting( $array = array() )
    {
        $return = $this->properties['settings'];
        foreach( $array as $a )
        {
            $return = $return[$a];
        }
        return $return;
    }
}
```

then use:

```
$Registry = new Registry();
$template = $Registry->getSetting(array( 'template' ) );
$template_caching = $Registry->getSetting(array( 'template', 'caching' ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use dot as separator for nested arrays:

```
Registry::getAttribute('first.second.1.value'); // will return $ar['first']['second'][1]['value']
```

In getAttribute explode param by `.` and map it into registry values.

Comment: This would leave me with the same issue though, however it has already been solved. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (untested):

```
function getSetting ( /* .. */ )
{
    $args = func_get_args();
    array_unshift( $args, $this->properties );

    return getSettingInternal( $args );
}

function getSettingInternal ( $args )
{
    $arr = $args[0];
    if ( count( $args ) > 1 )
    {
        $key = array_slice( $args, 1, 1 );
        if ( !is_array( $arr ) )
            return $arr;

        $arr = array_key_exists( $arr, $key ) ? $arr[$key] : $arr['default'];
        $args[0] = $arr;
        return getSettingInternal( $args );
    }
    else
        return $arr;
}
```